# MPMoviePlayerController slider/scrubber animation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using the MPMoviePlayerController for audio playback only. There is some strange behavior with the slider, where there is a delay when initial playback starts or when the playback is paused. The slider seems to glide for a few seconds until it reaches the proper position (sometimes speeding up/slowing down), like there is a delay in the sync between the animation and actual audio clip. The clip will also reach the end and stop before the slider reaches the end of the animation.

Has anybody seen this before? Is this a known bug or 'feature' of this component?